# Using assignment operator recursively

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, operator-keyword

Can someone tell me why the recursive `operator=` is not compiling here?  The task is straightforward.  I have a `Menu<T>` class, where `T` is the type in each option in the menu. The `Menu<WeightedItem<T>>` class is simply a specialization of `Menu<T>` where `WeightedItem<T>` contains the item `T` along with an `int` data member (for probability purposes).

I want to convert a `Menu<T>` to a `Menu<WeightedItem<T>>` by using its items and attaching some probability weights (whose values are not pertinent to the problem). The problem is that a menu can have submenus, which in turn can have submenus, hence I need the `operator=` to be used recursively. Here is my code so far:

```
template <typename T> struct WeightedItem;

template <typename T>
struct Menu
{
    struct Option
    {
        const T item;
        Menu* submenu;
        Option* next;
        Option(const T& t, Menu<T>* menu = nullptr) 
            : item(t),
            submenu(menu),
            next(nullptr)
        {}
    };

    Option* first; // first option in the menu
};


template <typename T>
struct WeightedItem {
    T item;
    int probabilityWeight;
};

template <typename T>
struct Menu<WeightedItem<T>>
{
    struct Option
    {
        const WeightedItem<T> item;
        Menu* submenu;
        Option* next;
        Option(const WeightedItem<T>& t, Menu<WeightedItem<T>>* menu = nullptr)
            : item(t),
            submenu(menu),
            next(nullptr)
        {}
        Option& operator=(const Option& other)
        {
            // Needed for defining Menu& operator=(const Menu<T>&).
            if (this == & other)
                return *this;
            item = other.item;
            submenu = other.submenu;
            next = other.next;
            return *this;
        }
    };
    Option* first;
    Menu & operator=(const Menu<T>&);
};

template <typename T>
Menu<WeightedItem<T>>& Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::operator=(const Menu<T>& other)
{
    delete first;
    if (!other.first)
        first = nullptr;
    else
    {
        int weight = 1;
        Menu<WeightedItem<T>> submenu operator=(*other.first->submenu); // Recursive operator= call for submenus.  Won't compile.
        first = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option({other.first->item, weight}, &submenu);
        Option* current = first->next;
        for (typename Menu<T>::Option* o = other.first->next; o; o = o->next)
        {
            Menu<WeightedItem<T>> submenu operator=(*o->submenu); // Recursive operator= call for submenus.  Won't compile.
            current = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option({o->item, ++weight}, &submenu);
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}

struct Item {};

int main() {
    Menu<Item> menu;
    Menu<WeightedItem<Item>> weightedMenu;
    weightedMenu = menu;
}
```

But the two recursive calls appear to be illegal.  Why?

```
[Error] expected initializer before 'operator'
```

If it is illegal, how to work around it?

Update:
Ok, all the deep copying carried out with several allocations with `new`.  I had to simply abandon the operator= idea and simply define a recursive function instead.  I tested that the results are accurate too:

```
template <typename T> struct WeightedItem;

template <typename T>
struct Menu {
    struct Option {
        const T item;
        Menu* submenu;
        Option* next;
        Option (const T& t, Menu<T>* menu = nullptr): item(t), submenu(menu), next(nullptr) {}
    };
    Option* first = nullptr;
};


template <typename T>
struct WeightedItem {
    T item;
    int probabilityWeight;
};

template <typename T>
struct Menu<WeightedItem<T>> {
    struct Option {
        const WeightedItem<T> item;
        Menu* submenu;
        Option* next;
        Option (const WeightedItem<T>& t, Menu<WeightedItem<T>>* menu = nullptr): item(t), submenu(menu), next(nullptr) {}
    };
    Option* first = nullptr;
    inline void inheritFrom (const Menu<T>&);
};

template <typename T>
inline void Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::inheritFrom (const Menu<T>& other) {
    if (!other.first)
        first = nullptr;
    else {
        int weight = 1;
        Menu<WeightedItem<T>>* submenu = nullptr;
        if (other.first->submenu) {
            submenu = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>;    
            submenu->inheritFrom (*other.first->submenu);  // Recursive call for submenus.
        }
        first = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option ({other.first->item, weight}, submenu);
        Option *current = first->next, *prev = first;
        for (typename Menu<T>::Option* o = other.first->next;  o;  o = o->next) {
            Menu<WeightedItem<T>>* submenu = nullptr;
            if (o->submenu) {
                submenu = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>;
                submenu->inheritFrom (*o->submenu);  // Recursive call for submenus.
            }
            current = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option ({o->item, ++weight}, submenu);
            prev->next = current;
            if (o->next) {
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Item {};

int main() {
    Menu<Item> menu;
    Menu<WeightedItem<Item>> weightedMenu;
    weightedMenu.inheritFrom(menu);
}
```

However, the original question regarding using = recursively still isn't answered.  And it appears that c++ doesn't support it, because when I tried to translate the above using =, it does not compile.

Comment: Please post the error message given by the compiler.

Comment: `Menu<WeightedItem<T>> submenu = *o->submenu;` doesn't call any `operator =`; it's an initialisation not an assignment.

Comment: Use `Menu<WeightedItem<T>> submenu operator= (*other.first->submenu);`?  Still does not compile.

Comment: You should not use word "operator" in your assignments.

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
   Menu<WeightedItem<T>> submenu operator=(*other.first->submenu);
   first = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option({other.first->item, weight}, &submenu);
```

by

```
   first = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option({other.first->item, weight}, &submenu);
   first->submenu->operator=(*other.first->submenu);
```

or by

```
   first = new Menu<WeightedItem<T>>::Option({other.first->item, weight}, &submenu);
   *first->submenu = *other.first->submenu;
```

That's a starting point to solve the problem but the real solution needs a deep copy of the options and submenu in each of the options.

Comment: But then `submenu` is not defined.  You mean `other.first->submenu` instead of `&submenu`?  That still does not compile.

Comment: @prestokeys, you need to add the logic to implement a deep copy of the submenu. Lookup code/logic to make a deep copy of singly linked lists to solve your problem.